# Pass value to a textbox using mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to pass a value to a textbox but this textbox can't be writable directly by the user. I'm calculating the value using jason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtid").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/CommissionsFinals/GetTarifa',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { clientID: $("#DDLCliente").val(), consultorID: $("#DDLConsultor").val() },

                success: function (tarifa) {
                    //response(tarifa.
                    $('#txtid').val(tarifa).autocomplete

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });

        })
    });
```

The textbox changes his value when i try to input a diferente value. The value is being calculated by the 2 parameters (clientId,consultorId) which are selected in 2 diferente DropDownLists. How do I get the value automatically after selecting those 2 values from the DropDownList?

```
<th>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.ManagerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Manager, "ManagerId", "NomeCompleto"), "Seleccione o Manager", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DDLManager" })
</th>
<th>
    @Html.Label("Consultor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ConsultorId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Consultor, "ConsultorId", "NomeCompleto"), "Seleccione o Consultor", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DDLConsultor" })
</th>
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Your view does not even contain a textbox.

Comment: `   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TarifaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                </th>
                <th>

                     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TarifaId, new { @id = "txtid" })
 
                </th>`

Comment: Edit your question with the code (not in comments). And what does your `GetTarifa` do and what does it return? (the code you have shown will give you errors in the browser console). And what do you mean by _"but this textbox can't be writable directly by the user"_? It is editable because you have not made it readonly.

Comment: The GetTarifa calculates a value from the 2 items selected from the DropDownLists 
[link] (http://s30.postimg.org/3qhihisrl/image.png)
[link] (http://s30.postimg.org/txipdhb1d/image.png)

Comment: Still not clear - if you dont want the `TarifaId` to be editable by the user, then it should be readonly, and you need to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlists to call the server method (or have a 'calculate' button and handle its `.click()` event to call the method).

Comment: i made it editable becouse it's the only way for that field to retrieve the value i want ...

Comment: No its not. Make it readonly (using `new { @readonly = "readonly" }` and then handle the `.change()` event of your dropdownlists to call that server method and update the value.

Comment: What you mean " handle the .change() event of your dropdownlists to call that server method and update the value"? I'm new to this technology, sorry for being so annoying.

Comment: Instead of `$("#txtid").change(function () {` its `$('#DDLCliente, #DDLConsultor).change() { ...})` but you will probably want other checks in your code such as not calling the server method if one or other of the values is `null` - i.e. the `Seleccione o Manager` or `Seleccione o Consultor` options are chosen

Comment: that didn't work but if i only put DDLCliente it does... but there's a problem that if I select the DDLConsultor first it wont retrieve the value.

Comment: Of course it works, but there are numerous other issues with your script but I see you have accepted an answer that does not answer the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the success callback from the ajax being called at all? 
$('#txtid').val(tarifa) should work but maybe that code is not being reached. You can test that with a breakpoint/alert or sth. Apart from that, I see one difference with my ajax calls, I usually use 
type: "POST", and that works for me.

Comment: i get the value that i want but only after I try to input a completely different value and click outside the textbox

Comment: I see your mistake, you are binding the ajax function to the CHANGE event of your textbox, but actually, it should be bound to the CHANGE event of your second dropdown!!  line 3($("#txtid").change(function () {), change txtid for DDLConsultor. Additionally, you could bind it to both dropdowns and validate if both of them have a valid value via js, as @user5566280 suggests in the post below

Comment: I didnt understand but this is what i have:
[link] (http://s22.postimg.org/y5e0mgrdt/image.png)
[link] (http://s22.postimg.org/uki538mu9/image.png)

Comment: you should change the line that says: `code`$("#txtid").change(function () { `code` for `code`$("#DDLConsultor").change(function () {`code`

Comment: That worked but...if i select the DDLConsultor first it won't retrieve the value. Is there a way to validate regardless who is selected first?

Comment: i mean if i select DDLCliente first and not DDLConsultor

Comment: sure, you need to add another .change function for your other dropdown(DDLManager). I would put the ajax call in a separate javascript function, and both Change functions would just validate if you have correct values, so then you only need to call the ajax. Lemme give you an example.

Comment: you're welcome, please mark the answer as correct if it was usefull!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the dropdown change event in Javascript with this

```
$("#test").change(function() {
    alert( "do you stuff" );
});
```

and check validation for two dropdown list is selected or not and finally call the ajax(jquery) method to submit the selected value to controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do. If you are asking about how to get selected value from a drop down, you may do this.

```
    $('#ConsultorId').on('change', function() {
        var consultorId = $('#ConsultorId').val();
    });
```